# In AWS .NET SDK apis, how do you specify "use default"

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

How do you specify the "default" value for a property in the APIs?

For example, the `RequestSpotInstance` API specifies that the "default" for `SpotPrice` is the On-Demand price, but it doesn't say how to specify default. The SpotPrice property of the RequestSpotInstancesRequest class is a string. Set it to `null`? `string.Empty`? `"0"` ?

Some of the fields are of types that are non-nullable, for example `int32`. In the same api, the "default" for the number of instances is 1. The property is an `int32`. So....do I request `0` instances in order to get the default of `1`? I would expect a `Nullable<int32>` instead to allow for a default.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the sdk source, null is to be used for specifying default. Makes sense, but not for value types. In fact there is no way to specify a default should be used for value types, the docs are wrong/misleading. These have internal nullable types but they are not exposed in the API.